# SQLite Slow Select Query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm running the following Select query:

```
SELECT "entry"."id" AS "entry_id",
"entry"."input" AS "entry_input",
"entry"."output" AS "entry_output",
"entry"."numOfWords" AS "entry_numOfWords",
"entry"."times_seen" AS "entry_times_seen",
"word_class"."value" AS "word_class_value",
"dominant_noun"."noun" AS "dominant_noun_noun",
"dominant_noun"."article" AS "dominant_noun_article",
"dominant_noun"."isPluaral" AS "dominant_noun_isPluaral",
"subject"."subjectIndex" AS "subject_subjectIndex",
"last_time_visited"."value" AS "last_time_visited_value"
FROM "entry" "entry"
LEFT JOIN "word_class" "word_class" ON "word_class"."entryId"="entry"."id"
LEFT JOIN "dominant_noun" "dominant_noun" ON "dominant_noun"."entryId"="entry"."id"
LEFT JOIN "subject_entries_entry" "subject_entry" ON "subject_entry"."entryId"="entry"."id"
LEFT JOIN "subject" "subject" ON "subject"."id"="subject_entry"."subjectId"
LEFT JOIN "last_time_visited" "last_time_visited" ON "last_time_visited"."entryId"="entry"."id"
WHERE "entry"."inputLang" = 31
AND ("entry"."input" like '% hilfe %' OR "entry"."input" like 'hilfe %' OR "entry"."input" like '% hilfe')
ORDER BY "word_class"."value" DESC, "entry"."numOfWords" ASC;
```

Time result:

```
real    0m15.100s
user    0m14.072s
sys     0m1.024s
```

Against this Database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "subject" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "subjectIndex" tinyint NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "entry" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "inputLang" tinyint NOT NULL, "outputLang" tinyint NOT NULL, "input"
varchar NOT NULL, "output" varchar NOT NULL, "numOfWords" tinyint NOT NULL, "times_seen" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT (0));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "abbr" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "value" varchar NOT NULL, "entryId" integer, CONSTRAINT "REL_ca935aaf7
66cba1e7bfbe90275" UNIQUE ("entryId"), CONSTRAINT "FK_ca935aaf766cba1e7bfbe902757" FOREIGN KEY ("entryId") REFERENCES "entry" ("id"));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "word_class" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "value" integer NOT NULL, "entryId" integer, CONSTRAINT "REL_941
45442deb2b2209bd943a787" UNIQUE ("entryId"), CONSTRAINT "FK_94145442deb2b2209bd943a7874" FOREIGN KEY ("entryId") REFERENCES "entry" ("id"));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "dominant_noun" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "noun" varchar NOT NULL, "article" tinyint NOT NULL, "isPluar
al" boolean NOT NULL, "entryId" integer, CONSTRAINT "REL_f493eeedea653d8a89f595c82c" UNIQUE ("entryId"), CONSTRAINT "FK_f493eeedea653d8a89f595c82c4" FOREI
GN KEY ("entryId") REFERENCES "entry" ("id"));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "last_time_visited" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "value" datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), "e
ntryId" integer, CONSTRAINT "REL_e631a6f55d59214f8e6aaa6447" UNIQUE ("entryId"), CONSTRAINT "FK_e631a6f55d59214f8e6aaa64478" FOREIGN KEY ("entryId") REFER
ENCES "entry" ("id"));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "subject_entries_entry" ("subjectId" integer NOT NULL, "entryId" integer NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "FK_d2eaa7a84a7963ed94e472cef0b"FOREIGN KEY ("subjectId") REFERENCES "subject" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE, CONSTRAINT "FK_5f940450dd4c681a9fecf0b14b2" FOREIGN KEY ("entryId") REFERENCES "entry" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE, PRIMARY KEY ("subjectId", "entryId"));
CREATE INDEX "IDX_3091789786b922bee00bbb44b1" ON "entry" ("inputLang") ;
CREATE INDEX "IDX_36ab3550b9e3ef647d1230affc" ON "entry" ("outputLang") ;
CREATE INDEX "IDX_1b0f6266dffb9a7e6343e7faa4" ON "entry" ("input") ;
CREATE INDEX "IDX_a77c7936ea412ec1958007154a" ON "entry" ("numOfWords") ;
CREATE INDEX "IDX_b32699a03d36223ff9bad94ea6" ON "entry" ("times_seen") ;
```

Explain result:

```
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     109   0                    00  Start at 109
1     SorterOpen     6     14    0     k(2,-B,B)      00
2     OpenRead       0     12    0     7              00  root=12 iDb=0; entry
3     OpenRead       1     2     0     3              00  root=2 iDb=0; word_class
4     OpenRead       7     3     0     k(2,,)         02  root=3 iDb=0; sqlite_autoindex_word_class_1
5     OpenRead       2     5     0     5              00  root=5 iDb=0; dominant_noun
6     OpenRead       8     6     0     k(2,,)         02  root=6 iDb=0; sqlite_autoindex_dominant_noun_1
7     OpenRead       3     10    0     2              00  root=10 iDb=0; subject_entries_entry
8     OpenRead       4     9     0     2              00  root=9 iDb=0; subject
9     OpenRead       5     7     0     3              00  root=7 iDb=0; last_time_visited
10    OpenRead       9     8     0     k(2,,)         02  root=8 iDb=0; sqlite_autoindex_last_time_visited_1
11    Rewind         0     92    0                    00
12      Column         0     1     1                    00  r[1]=entry.inputLang
13      Ne             2     91    1     (BINARY)       54  if r[1]!=r[2] goto 91
14      Column         0     3     4                    00  r[4]=entry.input
15      Function0      1     3     1     like(2)        02  r[1]=func(r[3..4])
16      If             1     23    0                    00
17      Column         0     3     6                    00  r[6]=entry.input
18      Function0      1     5     1     like(2)        02  r[1]=func(r[5..6])
19      If             1     23    0                    00
20      Column         0     3     8                    00  r[8]=entry.input
21      Function0      1     7     1     like(2)        02  r[1]=func(r[7..8])
22      IfNot          1     91    1                    00
23      Integer        0     9     0                    00  r[9]=0; init LEFT JOIN no-match flag
24      Rowid          0     10    0                    00  r[10]=rowid
25      SeekGE         7     87    10    1              00  key=r[10]
26      IdxGT          7     87    10    1              00  key=r[10]
27      DeferredSeek   7     0     1                    00  Move 1 to 7.rowid if needed
28      Integer        1     9     0                    00  r[9]=1; record LEFT JOIN hit
29      Integer        0     11    0                    00  r[11]=0; init LEFT JOIN no-match flag
30      Rowid          0     12    0                    00  r[12]=rowid
31      SeekGE         8     83    12    1              00  key=r[12]
32      IdxGT          8     83    12    1              00  key=r[12]
33      DeferredSeek   8     0     2                    00  Move 2 to 8.rowid if needed
34      Integer        1     11    0                    00  r[11]=1; record LEFT JOIN hit
35      Once           0     44    0                    00
36      OpenAutoindex  10    3     0     k(3,B,,)       00  nColumn=3; for subject_entries_entry
37      Rewind         3     44    0                    00
38        Column         3     1     13                   00  r[13]=subject_entries_entry.entryId
39        Column         3     0     14                   00  r[14]=subject_entries_entry.subjectId
40        Rowid          3     15    0                    00  r[15]=rowid
41        MakeRecord     13    3     1                    00  r[1]=mkrec(r[13..15])
42        IdxInsert      10    1     0                    10  key=r[1]
43      Next           3     38    0                    03
44      Integer        0     16    0                    00  r[16]=0; init LEFT JOIN no-match flag
45      Rowid          0     17    0                    00  r[17]=rowid
46      SeekGE         10    80    17    1              00  key=r[17]
47        IdxGT          10    80    17    1              00  key=r[17]
48        Integer        1     16    0                    00  r[16]=1; record LEFT JOIN hit
49        Integer        0     18    0                    00  r[18]=0; init LEFT JOIN no-match flag
50        Column         10    1     19                   00  r[19]=subject_entries_entry.subjectId
51        SeekRowid      4     76    19                   00  intkey=r[19]
52        Integer        1     18    0                    00  r[18]=1; record LEFT JOIN hit
53        Integer        0     20    0                    00  r[20]=0; init LEFT JOIN no-match flag
54        Rowid          0     21    0                    00  r[21]=rowid
55        SeekGE         9     72    21    1              00  key=r[21]
56        IdxGT          9     72    21    1              00  key=r[21]
57        DeferredSeek   9     0     5                    00  Move 5 to 9.rowid if needed
58        Integer        1     20    0                    00  r[20]=1; record LEFT JOIN hit
59        Rowid          0     24    0                    00  r[24]=rowid
60        Column         0     3     25                   00  r[25]=entry.input
61        Column         0     4     26                   00  r[26]=entry.output
62        Column         0     6     27    0              00  r[27]=entry.times_seen
63        Column         2     1     28                   00  r[28]=dominant_noun.noun
64        Column         2     2     29                   00  r[29]=dominant_noun.article
65        Column         2     3     30                   00  r[30]=dominant_noun.isPluaral
66        Column         4     1     31                   00  r[31]=subject.subjectIndex
67        Column         5     1     32                   00  r[32]=last_time_visited.value
68        Column         1     1     22                   00  r[22]=word_class.value
69        Column         0     5     23                   00  r[23]=entry.numOfWords
70        MakeRecord     22    11    35                   00  r[35]=mkrec(r[22..32])
71        SorterInsert   6     35    22    11             00  key=r[35]
72        IfPos          20    76    0                    00  if r[20]>0 then r[20]-=0, goto 76
73        NullRow        5     0     0                    00
74        NullRow        9     0     0                    00
75        Goto           0     58    0                    00
76        IfPos          18    79    0                    00  if r[18]>0 then r[18]-=0, goto 79
77        NullRow        4     0     0                    00
78        Goto           0     52    0                    00
79      Next           10    47    0                    00
80      IfPos          16    83    0                    00  if r[16]>0 then r[16]-=0, goto 83
81      NullRow        10    0     0                    00
82      Goto           0     48    0                    00
83      IfPos          11    87    0                    00  if r[11]>0 then r[11]-=0, goto 87
84      NullRow        2     0     0                    00
85      NullRow        8     0     0                    00
86      Goto           0     34    0                    00
87      IfPos          9     91    0                    00  if r[9]>0 then r[9]-=0, goto 91
88      NullRow        1     0     0                    00
89      NullRow        7     0     0                    00
90      Goto           0     28    0                    00
91    Next           0     12    0                    01
92    OpenPseudo     11    36    14                   00  14 columns in r[36]
93    SorterSort     6     108   0                    00
94      SorterData     6     36    11                   00  r[36]=data
95      Column         11    10    34                   00  r[34]=last_time_visited_value
96      Column         11    9     33                   00  r[33]=subject_subjectIndex
97      Column         11    8     32                   00  r[32]=dominant_noun_isPluaral
98      Column         11    7     31                   00  r[31]=dominant_noun_article
99      Column         11    6     30                   00  r[30]=dominant_noun_noun
100     Column         11    0     29                   00  r[29]=word_class_value
101     Column         11    5     28                   00  r[28]=entry_times_seen
102     Column         11    1     27                   00  r[27]=entry_numOfWords
103     Column         11    4     26                   00  r[26]=entry_output
104     Column         11    3     25                   00  r[25]=entry_input
105     Column         11    2     24                   00  r[24]=entry_id
106     ResultRow      24    11    0                    00  output=r[24..34]
107   SorterNext     6     94    0                    00
108   Halt           0     0     0                    00
109   Transaction    0     0     348   0              01  usesStmtJournal=0
110   Integer        31    2     0                    00  r[2]=31
111   String8        0     3     0     % hilfe %      00  r[3]='% hilfe %'
112   String8        0     5     0     hilfe %        00  r[5]='hilfe %'
113   String8        0     7     0     % hilfe        00  r[7]='% hilfe'
114   Goto           0     1     0                    00
```

Explain Query Plan output:

```
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN TABLE entry AS entry
|--SEARCH TABLE word_class AS word_class USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_word_class_1 (entryId=?)
|--SEARCH TABLE dominant_noun AS dominant_noun USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_dominant_noun_1 (entryId=?)
|--SEARCH TABLE subject_entries_entry AS subject_entry USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (entryId=?)
|--SEARCH TABLE subject AS subject USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
|--SEARCH TABLE last_time_visited AS last_time_visited USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_last_time_visited_1 (entryId=?)
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

Analyze output:

```
subject||1437631
entry|IDX_b32699a03d36223ff9bad94ea6|2348382 2348382
entry|IDX_a77c7936ea412ec1958007154a|2348382 67097
entry|IDX_1b0f6266dffb9a7e6343e7faa4|2348382 2
entry|IDX_36ab3550b9e3ef647d1230affc|2348382 1174191
entry|IDX_3091789786b922bee00bbb44b1|2348382 1174191
abbr|sqlite_autoindex_abbr_1|42575 1
dominant_noun|sqlite_autoindex_dominant_noun_1|823071 1
word_class|sqlite_autoindex_word_class_1|2005516 1
subject_entries_entry|sqlite_autoindex_subject_entries_entry_1|1437631 1 1
```

It often takes more than 10 seconds to get the results. Although this is my first time working with SQLite but 20 seconds reply time seems strange. Please add a comment if i should provide extra info in order to resolve the problem?

Comment: Aside - you do not need quotes around every identifier and one usually does not repeat the table name for table aliases which are typically shorter: `FROM entry e`.

Comment: @Parfait actually I'm using an ORM and the SQL is what it generates. And about the slowness of the select query?

Comment: Off the top of my head, the slowness can depend on the size of the database. It also depends on the joins because the joining columns are not indexed. Indexing them will improve the speed but be careful because indexing slows down updates.

Comment: What's the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output?

Comment: The order by also slows things down so if it is not needed, remove it. If it is then you cannot remove it obviously. The other question you need to answer is why are your not paging: What if your query returns thousands of rows?

Comment: @Shawn EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output is at the bottom.

Comment: @CodingYoshi thanks for your informational comments. I added analyze output to my question. Is it normal to get a query result after 20 seconds?. God i thought about ms reply times. Maybe my dream comes true in 50 years or so.

Comment: The automatic index used by the subject_entries_entry search is probably a big part of what you're seeing as it has to be rebuilt every time the query is run. Reversing the order of that table's composite primary key *might* help (along with making it a WITHOUT ROWID table if your ORM allows).

Comment: (if recreating tables with a new schema isn't feasible, at least try creating an index on `subject_entries_entry(entryId, subjectId)` and see if that starts being used. Might have to run a `pragma optimize` too.

Comment: @Shawn you are my hero. My timings dropped from 15seconds to less than half a second only by reversing `subject_entries_entry` composite primary keys. Do you have any other recommendations? Maybe you can provide an answer too.

Comment: I can expand on that in an answer, sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The factor to the long query times you're seeing is the `subject_entries_entry` table. It's a standard junction table used to relate rows in the `entry` table to rows in the `subject` table. The table definition uses a primary key that puts the subject id first, followed by the entry id (`PRIMARY KEY ("subjectId", "entryId")`).

Your query, on the other hand, first joins the entry id on the table, and then the subject id - the opposite of the order in the key. Sqlite can and does reorder the tables in a join to try to be as efficient as possible, but in this case it's not doing so. Going to the `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` output:

```
SEARCH TABLE subject_entries_entry AS subject_entry USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (entryId=?)
```

The `SEARCH` means it's looking up specific rows in an index instead of looking at every single one (`SCAN`), which is what you want, but the `AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX` part is bad. `AUTOMATIC` means that the query planner hasn't found an existing index it can use, but thinks using an index will be better than having to scan the table - so it builds a temporary one that exists just for that query. It looks like the `subject_entries_entry` table has a lot of rows, so this can take a while.

Recreating the table with the primary key columns in the same order they're used in the join cut the time down by a lot (As would a separate index with the columns flipped, at the expense of more disk space used).

My other advise for this table is making it a [WITHOUT ROWID](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) one. Normal sqlite tables use a 64-bit integer primary key (Known as rowid) regardless of what the table definition uses; a non-`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` is just a normal `UNIQUE` index in such a table. With `WITHOUT ROWID`, the primary key is the actual primary key of the table, saving space in cases like this where there's no real use for the actual rowid. Instead of a table and an index that duplicates the contents of each row, it just has a table. This optimization won't affect query speed, though, since it's using a *covering* index that has all needed information in the index already; the actual table isn't even looked at in the query as it is now.

I'm not sure about further speedups - looking at the query plan, it's using pre-existing indexes for the rest of the tables, and the join clauses are all straightforward. I'm a little surprised it's not using the index on `entry(inputLang)` to do a search instead of a scan on that table. Maybe if you can rebuild the sqlite library with [SQLITE_ENABLE_STAT4](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_stat4) turned on and then a [PRAGMA optimize](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_optimize) to rebuild the statistics tables, but that's getting into pretty advanced stuff depending on what language you're using (Easy in C or C++, harder in others).

Edit:

Some other things to explore:

- Enable multi-threaded sorting using [PRAGMA threads=N](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_threads) where N is the number of cores you're using.
- Enabling memory-mapped database with [PRAGMA mmap_size=X](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_mmap_size).

Comment: Thanks for your time and informative answer. BTW Merry Christmas, wish u good health and happiness.